# why is this simple prolog function failing?

Tags: prolog

I've written some simple father/parent/ancestor functions in Prolog.  Everything is working fine except ancestor.  Like this ...

```
?- parent(abe,homer).
true.

?- parent(homer,bart).
true.

?- ancestor(abe,bart).
false.
```

Why is my ancestor(abe,bart) returning false?  Here's my function …

```
%% returns true is X is an ancestor of Y, otherwise returns false
ancestor(X,Y) :-
  parent(X,Z),
  ancestor(Z,Y).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to add this to the database,

```
ancestor(A, B) :- parent(A, B).
```

since the parent of a child is an ancestor too.